# Why char *T = "hello"; doesnt give a memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I declared a simple string in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *t1 = "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

As you see, I dont have any `free` in my code. I checked it with `valgrind`, with this command:

`valgrind --tool=memcheck --track-origins=yes --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes -v --track-fds=yes ./test`

and it said that:

```
==4329== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4329==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4329==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==4329== 
==4329== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4329== 
==4329== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Why is that? I mean, I used a pointer `*T` but didnt free it anywhere. I thought it should give me a memory leak. Why not?

Comment: You have to (m)alloc something to leak something.

Comment: You don't have to `free()` anything if you didn't `malloc()` anything.

Comment: Just look at the valgrind output, it says "heap summary": heap is where dynamically allocated (i.e., `malloc`ed) things live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allocating memory.  You are creating a constant string in the data segment of your executable and assigning a pointer to point to that memory location.  Freeing it (or writing to that memory location) would be an error (undefined behavior).

Answer (score 2):

Its not an runtime memory allocation using `malloc`, which requires freeing it back. For this static allocation freeing the memory is done on program scope exit directly.